# How can I add additional style properties in CSS in Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I have a property which should set the font size of a text element. I've tried this so far:

```
<textarea 
  placeholder="Enter your TAX ID" 
  id="tax" 
  [(ngModel)]="tax_out" 
  [(ngModel)]="tax_in" 
  style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; bottom: 0px; fontsize: {{fontsize}}">
</textarea>
```

Unfortunately without success.

I get this in logcat:

> "WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value width: 100%; height: 100%;
>   position: relative; bottom: 0px; fontsize: (see
>   http://g.co/ng/security#xss)."
>
> "[WARN] TypeError: Cannot set property style of [object Object] which 
>   has only a getter"
>
> "ERROR", source: ng:///AppModule/ModalContentPage.ngfactory.js (154)
>
> "ERROR CONTEXT", source: ng:///AppModule/ModalContentPage.ngfactory.js (154)

Comment: Why do you have two `[(ngModel)]` attributes?

Comment: I was somewhat pedantic when debugging. I wanted to make sure I did not miss the promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just a single style, you can use **property binding** for this:

```
<textarea [style.font-size.px]="fontsize" ... style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; bottom: 0px;"></textarea>
```

Please take a look at the [ngStyle docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) for more info if you need to set more than one style dynamically:

```
<some-element [ngStyle]="{'font-style': styleExp}">...</some-element>    
<some-element [ngStyle]="{'max-width.px': widthExp}">...</some-element>    
<some-element [ngStyle]="objExp">...</some-element>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :) I've added some more info just in case if you also need to set more than one style at the same time...

Comment: When I read this section of the Angular docs things clicked for me https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#html-attribute-vs-dom-property Attributes initialize DOM properties. Then they're done. Property values can change, attribute values can't.

eg browser renders <input type="text" value="Bob">, it creates DOM node with value property initialised to "Bob".

User enters "Sally" into input box, DOM element value property becomes "Sally".  HTML value attribute remains unchanged. You discover if you ask the input element about that attribute: input.getAttribute('value') returns "Bob".

Comment: You're absolutely right. I've edited the answer to refer to _property binding_ instead. Just like you said, attribute binding would be something like this: `<button [attr.aria-label]="actionName">{{actionName}} with Aria</button>`. Thanks a lot for bringing this up :)