# ionic3 ngfor with different css

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I am looping a array list, and the object in it include a key value is 'isRead': 0/1,

and below is the the html code:

```
  <button ion-item text-wrap *ngFor="let notice of notices" ng-style="{ 'background': notice.isRead=='1': ? '#DCF7E3': '#FFFFFF' }">
  <ion-avatar item-start>
    <img src="{{notice.imageUrl}}" style="border-radius:0px;">
  </ion-avatar>
  <h3 [hidden]="slang!='en'" style="color:#172845;">{{notice.msgEN}}</h3>
  <h3 [hidden]="slang!='zh'" style="color:#172845;">{{notice.msgTW}}</h3>
</button>
```

My problem is I want to using "isRead" to have different background color, but now it seems not working, anyone have idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add additional style properties in CSS in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44883775/how-can-i-add-additional-style-properties-in-css-in-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid inline styles, you can change class like:

```
[ngClass]="{'class1': notice.isRead == 1, 'class2': notice.isRead == 0}"
```

then in your css file:

```
.class1 {
 background: #DCF7E3;
}
.class2 {
 background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

You can obviously change class names to be more relevant to purpose.